# How to understand this lambda with 3 .replace() line of code

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, replace, feature-engineering

`df['Current Ver'] = df['Current Ver'].astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.replace('.', ',',1).replace('.', '').replace(',', '.',1)).astype(float)`

Slowly learning lambda command, my understanding of this line of code is:

1. Change dataframe type to `str`
2. Apply `lambda` with one perimeter `x`
3. Replace all the string format `.` to `,` , (I don't understand what does `1` stands for, have done research prior asking, didn't find clue)
4. Replace all the string format `.` to `null` value
5. Replace all the string format `,` to `.` , (again still have no clue what does `1` stands for in this case)
6. Change dataframe type to `float`

Please help me better understanding this line of code, thank you

Comment: [third param to ``str.replace`` is explained in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) - and ``''`` is not a "null value", it's an empty string.

Comment: "Replace all the string format . to null value" no, to the empty string, i.e. removes that character from the string.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me find the correct way to understand this line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This replaces the first `.` in the string with a `,`, removes the remaining periods, changes the first `,` back to a `.`, then converts the result to a float for the `'Current Ver'` column in the dataframe.